# How to make Metrics of Soap service failed count, success count and average response count on Grafana

Tags: soap, prometheus, grafana

We have multiple soap services that is calling from multiple modules and I want to make metrics in Grafana of “failed count, success count and average response time of each service”. I can’t do any changes in any soap services because it is calling from multiple module so huge change will impact on project.

I defined the below annotation on soap service:-

@Timed(value = "soap_call", extraTags = {"job", "soapBLCRMSucheMarktprodukt_05_00"})

But by use of above annotation, I am able to get total count of this service. How will I identify this no of failed count and this no of success count, there is no "outcome or status field coming on prometheus endpoint" and also I used below query of average response time but it is giving incorrect output.

sum(rate(soap_call_seconds_sum{method="callBLCRMSucheMarktprodukt_05_00"}[$__range])) by (job)
/
sum(rate(soap_call_seconds_count{method="callBLCRMSucheMarktprodukt_05_00"}[$__range])) by (job)